# make google spread sheets cache current data and only pull in the new data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using [ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) script to pull in data from an API into google spreadsheets.

every time the function is called, it replaces the new data pulled in.
but I want the google spreadsheets to keep and cache the old data and only add the new data pulled in from the API.

how should I do this? Has anyone any idea?

Comment: You want to fix the value retrieved by "ImportJSON" to the cells. If my understanding is correct, how about put the values to the cells using "ImportJSON" with Google Apps Script instead of the custom function? By this, the values can be fixed to the cells. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: How are you using ImportJSON? As custom function or as script? What should happen to "old data"? Should it be kept in place or moved up/down, to another sheet,...?